# Testing randomized programs

Tags: python, testing

Are there any general strategies for testing randomized code? Functions, in particular. And in Python.

Suppose I have a function that should return the correct result ~95% of the time. The only way I can think of testing such a function is to run it many times and examine the number of times that it returned the correct result. Of course, this method does not necessarily imply correctness.

Are there any more complicated schemas (Python frameworks, maybe?) that facilitate testing of such programs?

Comment: I'd run the method 1000 times and assert that it returned the correct output between 94 and 96 percent of the time (or a larger error interval if it makes sense).

Comment: See e.g. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/147134/110531 - this isn't Python-specific

Comment: First thing on mine mind after reading your question is django and test driven development.